# JQuery - simple ajax requests don't work in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

I use jquery-1.7.1.min.js.

Simple example:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/test.php",
        data: "name=John&location=Boston"
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }); 

});

</script>
```

Show alert message in Opera, Chrome, FireFox, Safari, but don't show alert message in IE7-IE9. Where is problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Solved by adding header to the php part (test.php)

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this to use the 'success' parameter rather than the 'done' method. Also I changed the "language" attribute to "type"

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/test.php",
        data: "name=John&location=Boston",
        success: function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
    }); 
});

</script>
```

Comment: "Is there an error message shown in IE?" No, i don't see any errors and I don't understand where i can find mistake.

Comment: Btw, I tried this script on my other computer and it's work on IE 7-8, but don't work on IE9. WTF?!

Answer (score 0):

try including dataType alongwith other options that you have provided.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/test.php",
        data: "name=John&location=Boston",
        dataType: 'json', // <-- OR HTML,XML etc
        success: function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
    }); 
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/test.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    dataType: "text",
    complete: function(msg,status) {alert( "Data Saved: " + msg.responseText );}
  });
});
</script>
```

Another solution, try the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $.post('/ajax/test.php',{name:'John',location:'Boston'},
         function(data) {alert( "Data Saved: " + data );}
      );
    });
</script>
```

And add, in your test.php header :

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
echo "It works !" // Be positive :-)
?>
```

Comment: only this code see ie9. i wrote in test.php only one line of code: echo "test"; In IE 9 ajax return alert message "Data Saved: undefined"! Why?! In another browsers it's work good.

Comment: May I advice you to put the entire url of your http://...domain.../test.php. Have a look to my second solution. And tell me if it works.